# Marker out of bounds on Google Maps API v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API v3 to show a world map, that is static (It doesn't allows to be zoomed or dragged). Above it there is a dragabble marker with a custom icon, and a set of circles of different radius binded to it.

The actual map code is:

```
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.283, 13.843);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      maxZoom:2,
      minZoom:2,
      draggable: 0,
      center: myLatlng,
      streetViewControl: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapaGoogle"),
      mapOptions);

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('path/to/imageplaneminiature.png',
    new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(18, 20));

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: myLatlng,
      icon: markerImage,
      draggable: true
    });
```

And then for each circle I've:

```
    planes[1] = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 2500000,
      strokeColor: "#cccccc",
      fillOpacity: 0
    });

    planes[1].setMap(map);
    planes[1].bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

This is working good, but I have 2 problems:

1) When the user drags the marker near to a border, as the world is round, the radius shows also in the other side. But it doesn't shows the marker in its scenter, and that doesn't looks so cool. Look at the picture:
[image: buggy map]

2) If the user drags the marker out of the map area, it remains invisible and the user is unable to bring it back. Its there any way to force it to be inside of the viewport area?

Comment: It seems markers will display on both sides only if they are not draggable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no option to choose if a marker will be repeated or not at lower zoom levels. Markers with draggable:false will be repeated.

To prevent a user to drag a marker outside of the map bounds, all I can think about is checking whether the marker position fits the map bounds or not, and moving it back to the last position if out of bounds.

You can do something like

```
if (map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
    // marker is within map bounds
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/c4gaC/

Note that if you want to prevent users from zooming the map, you also have to set the two following options:

```
scrollwheel: false
disableDoubleClickZoom: true
```

**Edit:**

Here is a *hack* for the repeating markers. It draws a non draggable marker beneath the draggable one, hides it when dragging starts and shows it again when dragging stops. This way your marker will be repeated.

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/m76km/

**Note that this will lead to 2 issues:**

1. Only one of the two displayed markers is draggable which is clearly confusing.
2. This will lead to some display issues if using PNG marker icons with transparency.

Opacity would not be an issue with the circle because you could bind it to only one of the two markers.